# Modifying WordPress' post fullscreen editor (distraction free writing) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the content of WordPress' fullscreen editor accessable on the post edit page (also called *[distraction free writing](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/editors/distraction-free-writing/)*) using jQuery.

I've tried to edit the content directly by, as an example, using `jQuery(".wp-fullscreen-title").hide();` which is supposed to hide the title input element that is being displayed in the fullscreen editor - but it didn't work. Executing the script with `jQuery(".wp-fullscreen-editor").ready(function() { ... });` also doesn't work.

Do you have any more ideas on how to edit the content of the fullscreen editor with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You're running jQuery incorrectly.

This won't work because the DOM hasn't yet loaded (meaning the browser hasn't yet created each of the elements specified in html, including your title field):

```
jQuery(".wp-fullscreen-title").hide();
```

This is just plain wrong:

```
jQuery(".wp-fullscreen-editor").ready(function() { ... });
```

And this is what you need:

```
// this is the standard way to wait until the DOM is ready, then run the code inside.
jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
  // now that the DOM has loaded you can hide the field.
  jQuery(".wp-fullscreen-title").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had forgotten to mention that all the code is within the jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... }); code already. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: well then something else is going on.  i just tried myself and that code works.  check your javascript console.  any error messages?

Comment: No, that's the thing, no message or whatsoever. But since it works with you, I'll give it a try with a clean WP. Maybe some plugins mess something up. Thanks for your help so far.